# How do i append copied text to clipboard on a new line?

Tags: linux, clipboard, copy-paste, clipboardmanager

I am doing a task which requires me to copy urls of many vidoes using a chrome extension and paste them in a text file . Currently i am doing it one by one . I am just trying to save some time as currently its very time consuming.

So unlike the default behaviour where if we copy any text , it replaces the clipboard content , i want the copied text to get appended on a new line and all of the text should be pasted together when i paste it at the last . I couldn't really find anything that could help me . Would be glad to know any workaround for this .

I have seen some solutions but they are only specifically working for anything copied from terminal ,it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Consider keyboard macros - or some other keystroke automation for the platform you are on.  For instance, let's say you had the _Notes_ application open in addition to chrome.  You could record a macro to:  Copy + Switch Apps + Paste + Newline + Switch Apps + (and maybe tab)

Comment: @Mark that's something i didn't really thought of . Thanks a ton i will definitely try it..  Although i haven't ever used macro so don't know about its capabilities. Before i dive in , learn and use it.  Just one question - Can a macro be made to click dynamically each time below the previous video and scroll up  once it has reached the bottom of the page (since my target website is similar , just think of it as you want to copy the url of vidoes from youtube through a extension - open video , click extension , copy , paste , click on below video , extension , copy paste and so on )..

Comment: I am just asking about about the possibility of doing it . i will obviously learn and do it myself. I just don't want to put some hours and then realise its not achievable

Comment: The scrolling may be achieved in some apps by using the down arrow.  I've found apps on windows platforms to be much more keyboard friendly that MacOS.  I suggest that you try your procedure first using the keyboard only.  If you can accomplish your task repeatedly by hitting the same keys, a macro will very likely work for you.  On a Mac?  Maybe consider looking at the automator.

Comment: @Mark using arch linux